# Why i cannot quit this while loop(java)?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am new here and i got into trouble about my coding, i hope someone could help me break this loop, cause no matter what i type, it always in the loop.My code is as follow:

```
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the movie's title:");
        title = s.nextLine().trim();
        if(title.trim().equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("Please do not enter an empty title!");
        }
        else 
        {
            for(Movie m: movies)
            {
                if(title.equals(m.getTitle().trim()))
                {
                    System.out.println("Title already exists!");
                }
                else
                {
                    m.setTitle(title);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the perfect chance to try a debugger or unit tests. Debuggers let you step through your code one statement at a time. Unit tests let you verify your functions by running them against expected inputs and outputs. Either will help you solve your problem. (Unit tests work better with smaller functions though)

Comment: Presumably there is no movie whose name does not equal the title entered, or you keep entering all whitespace.

Comment: Note that you don't need to trim again in the first if. It doesn't hurt much, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: @AndyTurner if i wanna quit this while loop, what should i do next?

Comment: @byxor Thanks for your advice, i will try it.

Comment: What is being printed to screen when you enter a title that is not in the existing movies collection? That will help to trace which branch seems to be causing the problem.

Would be helpful to provide an example of the exact inputs you tried with the associated outputs

Comment: @Adam enter a title different to any of your movies' titles. If you have zero movies, that's not possible, so you might want to consider checking `movies.isEmpty()`.

Comment: @BrandonBodnar "Please enter the movie's title:" it always show that in terminal window.

Comment: If it just keeps displaying "Please enter the movie's title:", then I think @AndyTurner is spot on. Sounds like movies is empty, and thus the for loop never executes.

Comment: @BrandonBodnar   Yes, you are right, the movies is empty, but what if i still could quit this loop, even if this 'movies' is empty

Comment: That is where @AndyTurner other comment comes in. Add an if check to see if movies is empty and set flag to false in that case. That if check would need to be outside the for loop (either before or after works).

Comment: @Brandon or simply use `boolean flag = !movies.isEmpty();`, since there is presumably no point in entering the name if there are no movies to rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an little known feature of Java labeled breaks.

Example from the [officials docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html):

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

    search:
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                 j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

So you basically have to put a label, e.g., `outer:` before the actual loop and then you can use `break outer;` to break out of the outer loop instead of the inner loop. Note this also works with `continue`.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it later

Answer (score 0):

The break leaves for loop, but you still need one more break to exit while loop.

Comment: the `flag` is set to `false`, before breaking.

Comment: I'm not quite understand, cause i have set the "flag" to "false"...it should quit while loop

Comment: I suspect that it's never reaching that code. `title.equals(m.getTitle().trim())` might always be returning `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(title.trim().equals(""))
    {
        System.out.println("Please do not enter an empty title!");
         flag=flase;
    }
```

and here also

```
 if(title.equals(m.getTitle().trim()))
            {System.out.println("Title already exists!"); 
flag=false;
break;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a small logical problem.
When you start entering the movie names, you are gonna stop input/entering the values at some point, right?.
The program must also know that so add a condition check ***title.trim().equals("break")***

```
boolean flag = true;
        while(flag)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the movie's title:");
            title = s.nextLine().trim();
            if(title.trim().equals(""))
            {
                System.out.println("Please do not enter an empty title!");
            }
            else if(!title.trim().equals("break")) 
            {
                for(Movie m: movies)
                {
                    if(title.equals(m.getTitle().trim()))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Title already exists!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m.setTitle(title);
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
   }
```

The above code should do the trick.
Let me know if the problem still persists @Adam.

Answer (score 0):

initially when you enter your first title there are no objects inside "movies" sequence which "for" loop can go through, thus I believe your code initially never enters the "for" loop and continues.

I recommend use a if(movies == null) statement before for loop to check for empty sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, my movies is empty at first and i need to add some objects at first, i add the flag = null statement into if(movies == null) but it still didn't work

Comment: Why are you giving a boolean variable null. Just check weather the movies sequence is empty. if so just add the title into the sequence and set flag = false and break.